# Toolbar Menu text Alignment

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar, text-alignment, overflow-menu

I have already made my custom Style for Toolbar Overflow Menu.

```
 <style name="custompopupOverflowMenu" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/drop_down_back_0</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF4081</item>

        <item name="android:textDirection">rtl</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">textEnd</item>
    </style>
```

this is background shape:

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

and have used it in my toolbar:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:titleTextColor="#fff"

        app:popupTheme="@style/custompopupOverflowMenu">
```

The background shape and text color have changed correctly. The problem is that "text alignment", "text direction" and "text gravity" were not affected. Of course I checked them separately, but I put them here together just to review them

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the alignment, direction & gravity  in the androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar, and NOT on the style section?

Comment: yes I have tested that also. no effect on menu items

Comment: can you upload the 'drop_down_back_0' from the drawable folder?

Comment: Maybe instead of "gravity", you must try writing "layout-gravity"?

Comment: Add in your `custompopupOverflowMenu` the item `<item name="android:layoutDirection">inherit</item>` or `<item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>`

Comment: what alignment are you looking for? because in the attached screenshot texts are correctly placed in rtl end. if you want center alignment you should set `textAlignment` to center.

Comment: also if not working try setting `textAppearanceLargePopupMenu` and `textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu` attributes in your style.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I`v checked them before. Nothing happened.